# SQLite query delete in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i want to execute a query  like this....

```
delete FROM employees where hired_on >= date('now', 'start of day', '-30 days');
```

It tried to execute

```
String dateLimit = "date('now', 'start of day', '-30 days')";

database.delete(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME + " >= ? ", new String[]{dateLimit});

database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME  + " >= " + dateLimit);
```

but didn't worked....

what should i have to do?

thanks in advance......

**EDIT**

Example data for column is

```
 2016-03-21 06:22:36
 2016-03-22 07:47:19
 2015-12-22 17:42:23
 2015-12-21 19:01:05
 2015-06-28 09:46:16
```

and column type is `text`

Comment: Why didnt it work, did it throw an error? If so check the logs

Comment: no error no exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can be used only for literal values.
What you tried to execute is the same as:

```
delete FROM employees where hired_on >= 'date(''now'', ''start of day'', ''-30 days'')';
```

where everything after the `>=` is a single string.

To execute an SQL function such as `date`, you must write it directly into the SQL query:

```java
db.delete(TABLE_NAME,
          COLUMN_NAME + " >= date('now', 'start of day', '-30 days')",
          null);
```

Comment: Then the format of the column's values (which you did not mention) is wrong.

Comment: values format is like this `2016-03-21 06:22:36`
and column type is `text`

but it work in this [link](https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/)

Comment: Put this information, and some example data, into the question.